# PdfXChange "Errors detected in the XREF table" after PDFBox modifcation

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to modify an existing PDF with PDFBox. But every time PDF-XChange gives me a warning saying that "Errors detected in the XREF table".
So I tried just opening the PDF via
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
and then without doing anything else save it:
document.save("my_doc.pdf");

But even here I get the same message from PDF-XChange.
I don't get this message with the original PDF.

Any ideas?

Comment: There indeed are pdfbox versions which created erroneous cross reference structures. Thus, please do indicate the version you use. Furthermore, if that issue only occurs with some pdfs, not all, please share an example pdf to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I use PDFBox version 2.0.24. Links to the original pdf and the pdfbox modified version are here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnsk189x2kch6wj/test_after_pdfbox_modification.pdf?dl=0) and here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5o0r8u3nutt8aa/test.pdf?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warn message from PDF-XChange after signing PDF files using Apache PDFBox v3.0-alpha2. After some investigation, I realized that I run into this issue only when I work on PDF files which were generated by MS Word.

By now I could not find the exact explanation but eventually found the following workaround that works for me. Before I sign the `PDFDocument`, I let it save into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` **without** compression:

```
. . .
PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(inFile)
try(ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
  doc.save(baos, CompressParameters.NO_COMPRESSION);  
} 
// Now go on with signing or other work with the PDDocument 
// ...
```

This "dummy saving" of the `PDFDocument` seems to have a "healing" side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in Apache PDFBox. I ended up using itext to do the flattening.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

code:

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;

public class MyClass {

    public static void flattenPDF(String src, String dest) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);

        // If no fields have been explicitly included, then all fields are flattened.
        // Otherwise only the included fields are flattened.
        form.flattenFields();

        pdfDoc.close();
    }

}
```